# Recursive functions - factorials

Tags: function, recursion, factorial

I am trying to wrap my head around the factorial calc example for recursive functions, I always get lost when trying to track the flow of the recursive function itself. Does it return the value for a * (a - 1) for every iteration? Why does it not return a value of 1? Simple words only plz newb here :)

```
// factorial calculator
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long factorial (long a)
{
  if (a > 1)
   return (a * factorial (a-1));
  else
   return 1;
}

int main ()
{
  long number = 9;
  cout << number << "! = " << factorial (number);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you are rewriting the lines of code as it is being evaluated. For instance, suppose you call:

```
factorial(3)
```

In the factorial function, your variable `a` has the value 3. So the if condition evaluates to true. That means your entire if statement could be rewritten as `return (a * factorial (a-1))` but with the value 3 replacing `a`. So you have:

```
(3 * factorial (3-1))
```

Continuing, the `3-1` would be evaluated leaving:

```
(3 * factorial (2))
```

The next step is to evaluate the call to `factorial(2)`. In this call the variable `a` has the value 2 so the if condition again evaluates to true and can be rewritten as:

```
(3 * 2 * factorial(2-1))
```

Then the `2-1` is evaluated so you get:

```
(3 * 2 * factorial(1))
```

The call to `factorial(1)` is then evaluated. This time `a` has the value 1 and the if condition is false. That means it can be rewritten as just 1:

```
(3 * 2 * 1)
```

Then the `3 * 2` is evaluated:

```
(6 * 1)
```

Then the `6 * 1` is evaluated:

```
(6)
```

The parentheses don't matter here (but you have them in your code) so this is actually:

```
 6
```

Comment: This is the explanation that Ive been looking for. Thank you, I always thought the recursive function itself would only keep looping until it reaches 1 and only returns a value of 1, I skipped the part where it would actually store (6*5*4*..(a-1))

Answer (score 0):

Because the method is calling itself, as thus it is called recursive. A recursive function must have a code that stops the execution when a criteria is met, such as in your code, it is

> when a <= 1 it returns 1

A recursive function relies on Stack, when you call factorial(9), the function actually says "oops, I dont have the answer yet, but I know that factorial(9) is actually 9 * factorial(9-1). So excuse me, I am going to call factorial(8) now and wait if anything is actually working in the future"

Then the code eventually met with factorial(1), then it stops and says "factorial of 1 is 1 itself", it knows this very well which I call it a stop point of a recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

Stop trying to track everything through the recursive calls, and think of a recursive function as actually being a function.  It just happens to call itself sometimes.  When you pass a function an argument, you don't need to know what's going on behind the wall. A function is an abstraction for the work that's being done, and hands back the correct answer based on its argument.  When you use `exp()` or `log()` or `cos()`, for example, you don't need to know how it actually works in order to use it.

This is where you have to make the recursive leap of faith—"If I can trust this function to hand me the right answer for a smaller problem, then I can construct the answer for my current problem."  For factorials, the right answer is 1 for `n` equal to zero or one, and it's `n * factorial(n - 1)` for `n > 1`.  You can confirm this by writing that formulation for a small case:

4! = 4 * 3! = 4 * (3 * 2!) = 4 * (3 * (2 * 1!)) = 4 * (3 * (2 * 1))

Yup, that's pretty much the arithmetical definition of 4!.

Now look at the recursive implementation you posted, slightly reordered, and see the direct correspondence:

```
long factorial(long a) {  // If I trust this function...
  if (a <= 1)   // when a is 0 or 1
    return 1;   // I know the answer is 1.
  else          // Otherwise, trust the answer for the smaller case of (a-1) and 
    return (a * factorial(a-1));         // multiply that answer by a to get a!.
}
```

If you're willing to make that recursive leap of faith, then a lot of otherwise very complex functions practically write themselves.